# DeviceOrientationEvent.askPermission() not prompting anything

Tags: javascript, accelerometer, ios13, mobile-website, device-orientation

I want access to the accelerometer data on a phone.

In iOS 13 you must expressly ask for permission to get that data.

My dev setup is running `webpack-dev-server` using `--https`, testing on my local network on my iPhone (iOS 13.3, Safari).

1. I first call `checkOrientation()` - this returns `true` when it's on iOS (e.g. my desktop client returns `false`).
2. If `checkOrientation()` returns `true`, I call `askOrientation()`. This Promise calls the `DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()` method and then `if (response == 'granted') return true;` and then call 
   `window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);`

On mobile Safari I'm getting to the response from the Promise, but I get an error in the console: `DOMException{}` with no more info. response=='granted' is returned false, but I never get any sort of prompt before that.

Here's most of the code:

```
exports.checkOrientation = function(){
      console.log("PermissionsMgr asking Orientation");
      if(typeof(DeviceOrientationEvent) !== 'undefined' && typeof (DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission) === 'function'){
        //ios13
        return true;
      }else{
        // not ios13
        return false;
      }
    }
```

// if checkOrientation() == true, then I call askOrientation():

```
exports.askOrientation = function(){
    DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()
        .then(response => {
            if(response=='granted'){
                hasGranted=true;
            }else{
                hasGranted=false;
            }
            return hasGranted;
        })
        .catch(console.error)
}
```

Question: How do I get the prompt to appear on my mobile device when i call DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?